# How do I select the value of a namespaced attribute with SXD-XPath?

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, rust, rdf

I have the following XML:

```xml
<ultradata xml:id="deadbeef" rdf:resource="http://some-resource/ultralink">Some stuff</ultradata>
```

I want to get the value of `rdf:resource`, but I cannot figure out how to do namespacing. My namespace registration:

```rust
let mut context = sxd_xpath::Context::new();
context.set_namespace("xml", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace");
context.set_namespace("rdf", "https://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns");
```

It seems that there is no `resource` at https://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns.

`@xml:id` works, but `@rdf:resource` does not. From the same context, of course.

This namespace stuff is really weird. How can I select the value of `rdf:resource`?

Comment: Try `http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns` or `http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#` instead of `https://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns`.

Comment: Works! Thank you.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell the complete XML that is input, which includes the namespace definitions. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the RDF RFC](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/#section-Namespace), the RDF namespace URI is `http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#`.

Assuming that your input XML properly defines this namespace:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<outer xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <ultradata xml:id="deadbeef" rdf:resource="http://some-resource/ultralink">Some stuff</ultradata>"
</outer>
```

Then you need to use the same namespace in the code:

```
static INPUT: &str = r##"<?xml version="1.0"?>
<outer xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <ultradata xml:id="deadbeef" rdf:resource="http://some-resource/ultralink">Some stuff</ultradata>"
</outer>
"##;

fn main() {
    let package = sxd_document::parser::parse(INPUT).expect("Invalid XML");
    let doc = package.as_document();

    let mut context = sxd_xpath::Context::new();
    context.set_namespace("rdf", "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#");

    let xpath = sxd_xpath::Factory::new().build("//@rdf:resource").expect("Invalid XPath").expect("No XPath");
    let value = xpath.evaluate(&context, doc.root()).expect("Cannot evaluate XPath");

    if let sxd_xpath::Value::Nodeset(ns) = value {
        for n in ns {
            println!("{:?}", n);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Disclaimer: I am the author of SXD-XPath and SXD-Document